# Is the size limit of a json field before or after compression in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, json

The size limit of a json field is 1GB ([source: this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632871/size-limit-of-json-data-type-in-postgresql)):

> `json` is the same as a `text` datatype but with JSON validation. The `text` datatype's maximum size is 1GB.

I ran some experiments with inserting `json` of varying sizes into a table in Postgres.
Taking `pg_sizeof` of rows here seems to indicate that Postgres does compression of the json data.

My experiment:

```
create table json_size (n integer, j json);
```

For `n` with values of 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10 000, 100 000, 1 000 000.

```
with q as (select generate_series(1, n)::bigint as x)               
insert into json_size (n, j)
select 1, coalesce(json_agg(to_json(q.*)), '[]'::json) from q;
```

```
select n, pg_column_size(j) as size from json_size;
```

Results

```
n       size
1       10
10      92
100     996
1000    3224
10000   33488
100000  335115
1000000 3351365
```

Is the size limit of 1GB before or after this compression is done?

Comment: What PostgreSQL version you're asking about? in recent versions JSON (and JSONB) is separate datatype. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html And no size limit is claimed for it. 1Gb limit is general column size limit. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html

Comment: why doy ou think that piostgres compresses json?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The limit of 1GB on `varlena` data types like `json` is *before* compression.

Note that you will need a lot of RAM to read and write such values. It is usually a problem and bad design to store such large values in a database.